# Adding a responsive grid onto a page (without using a Bootstrap theme)

Tags: plugins, css, screen-layout

I'd like to add tiles like this onto my page: http://www.dorsetveganevents.co.uk/exhibitors—new-forest-2016.html

I've searched for and tried a few plugins (WP Tiles, Content View etc) but they all require the information to be stored as pages or posts which will break other sections.

Should I hard code it in as HTML?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different grid systems available that can be incorporated into WordPress, usually simply by enqueueing the stylesheets for them. Then you can hard-code the HTML by adding `div` tags with the appropriate classes for that system.

Here's a good list of different grid system examples:

- [Skeleton Boilerplate](http://getskeleton.com/)
- [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/)
- [Responsive Grid System](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/playground/)
- [Mesh (Plugin)](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/mesh/)
- [BioShip (Theme)](http://bioship.space)

It may also be worth looking at including and applying jQuery matchHeight, as depending on the application it may also be desirable to normalize row heights.